# Solr/Lucene result field term count

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I am using solr to do a search. As result I get back a set of fields. One of the fields is "domains". The domain field is a many to many relationship in my database, so my docs contain an array of "domains" the are linked to.

What I want to do is, for each domain in the resultset, count how many times this "domain term" is found in the global result set.

How should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the [Field collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) feature.

Comment: The problem is that it's a multivalued field

Comment: Wiki says support for multivalued fields is not implemented, so I guess the only option you have is to iterate and count yourself. Or change the data model ;-(